# SQL not returning any records

Tags: mysql

I have an weird issue, I am running the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_statement_items;
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_statement_items`;
```

The table 'tbl_statement_items' contains 28 records, however when I run the command above its showing 0 results found.

However when I run it through phpmyadmin it displays all the records: (it appends a limit).

```
SELECT * FROM  `tbl_statement_items` WHERE 1 LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Am I missing something simple here or has anyone else experienced this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you querying mysql directly or through a language method like `mysql_query()` in PHP? If the later is true, can I see a PHP snippet?

Comment: How are you running the statement the first time? Are you sure your querying the correct database. Try database.tablename syntax.

Comment: In my experience with similar cases, 99% of times you just are querying the wrong copy of the database.

Comment: Thanks for the responses: Its the only DB configured, we use some software called Navicat. We use PDO, but the class is been built which will interact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the issue is likely the method in which you are querying your data, make sure of the following (these examples apply to PHP):

```
// Your connection to the database is properly set up
$con = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or exit;
mysql_select_db( $dbName, $con );

// You are storing your query in a variable to be processed
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM tbl_statement_items');

// And you are using the appropriate functions to extract your content
while ($resultArray = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    foreach ($resultArray as $record) {
        // Yada yada yada...
    }
}
```

This of course is not all encompassing and your issue could be a number of other things, but why not start by double checking the fundamentals, right?

Comment: @65Fbef05: Thank you, we use PDO, atm we are just running the queries via navicat and phpmyadmin so we know the expected behaviour.

Comment: So the complication is that Navicat isn't returning any records with your query?

Comment: @65Fbef05: Yes that is correct, we never have had any issues with Navicat before.

Comment: Are you able to successfully return other queries to the same database right now?

Comment: Yes we can retrieve data from the other tables

Comment: Interesting... Is there anything different about this table like collation or character encoding that Navicat might not be configured for?

Comment: In your database's `information_schema` table (might be named something different), is tbl_statement_items set up with different user privileges or constraints than your other tables? Are you accessing all tables with the same user?

Comment: @65Fbef05: the table was created under the same user, it works in phpmyadmin

Comment: I'm stumped... The only other thing I can recommend if this table is altogether inaccessible is to back it up, drop it, then create a new one. Good luck to ya'.

Comment: @65Fbef05: Thanks, thats what we are thinking. The data in there is only dummy data as its on the development box. Thanks for your help. +1

Comment: No problem at all; sorry I couldn't figure out a quick solution for you. I certainly empathize - it's frustrating as hell being unable to pinpoint a problem.